# how to handle expiring access token from partner api

Tags: next.js, access-token

I'm new to Next js. I'm sure this is a common issue but I don't know what to search for. Here's an outline:

One of my partners has an API with Bearer auth. The Bearer token comes from an endpoint I call (`/auth`) with my username and password. That endpoint returns the Bearer token that I use for all other endpoints, but it expires in one day.

How would I handle making API calls on Next.js API routes to this partner? I.e. where would I store this access token so each API route doesn't need to constantly fetch it. And, how do I update it when it expires?

Answer (score 0):

Your clients (once authenticated) should be the ones "storing" these tokens.  You would basically need to fetch it from the client's session, cookie, or however you are storing those.

As far as updating these tokens, your auth provider should also provide a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve a new jwt once it has expired.  The purpose here is that you'll be able to refresh the token for the user without requiring them to log in again.

Depending on your provider, this may be a new endpoint you'll need to call.

https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned I'm doing this in a Next API route acting as a webhook. Not sure if I can access the client's browser or anything like that... maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making calls to your partner's api when you go to a specific route(like a protected one), then you should store your access token as cookie with http-only flag to avoid security issues like xss attacks that can steal the session data from your browser(*the http-only flag should be set in the `/auth` route in your partner's api when he sends the response with the token*), so make the calls within the **getServerSideProps** sending the cookie with the request, so your partner should take the token from the cookie and validate it to allow the request, one thing i need to point out is that you can't access an http-only cookie from client side, but as you are using nextJs you can still access it from **getServerSideProps** with a library called **nookies**, so you could do something like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ctx => {
  const cookies = nookies.get(ctx)
  const someApiData = await fetchApiData(cookies)

  if (!someApiData) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        // Redirect to home if not authorized
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }

  return {
  //return data fetched from the api
    props: {
      someApiData
    }
  }
}
```

and the function that makes the api call, could look like this(note that i'm using axios):

```
const fetchApiData = async (cookies: CookieData) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get<ApiData>('/some/api/route', {
      // Pay attention to this line, here we are sending the cookie with the access token
      headers: {
        Cookie: `token=${cookies.token}; HttpOnly;`
      }
    })
    return result.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Note that you should send the cookie whenever you make a request to a protected route and your partner should validate this token in each route that he wants to protect.
And to refresh the token without login again, your partner can implement a refresh token like @SLee mentioned. This is just an example but you got the idea.

Comment: Hi as mentioned, I'm making calls when the partner API pings my webhook (which is a next js api route). I'm not sure if I'll have access to cookies? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's possible, maybe what you are looking for is [iron session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session), with this library you can create a session from your nextJs api, so you can store the token in the session and further get it back to send with the request, although without any code it's hard to know if it will work in your case, so include some code if you want more help